# Limit clicking on datatable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a datatable on which I'm printing the results of a query I get from a database, the general look of this table is as follows:

```
<table  id="dt-inventory-list" class="table table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>Field</th>
            <th>ACTION</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, as you can see, there's a column called ACTION , in this row, I'm procedurally adding an 'a' tag so the user can add this info to another datatable, I'm doing this inside an AJAX datasrc:

```
inventory.action = '<a data-id="'+inventory.idInventory+'" onclick="addRow('+inventory.idInventory+')" ondblclick="return false" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-plus-circle"></i></a>';
```

I do have validations preventing it from adding the item twice, my problem is that when a user double clicks this 'a' tag too fast, it jumps that validations and adds it twice. Is there a way I can limit this to only work on the first click, or to only register one click event every say, 2 or 3 seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have tagged your question jQuery, I will answer with a jQuery solution. Instead of defining onclick in your  element, create the element and then bind the click handler using `.one()`:

```
$('<selector for your link>').one('click', function () {
    addRow(this.data('id'));
});
```

`.one` binds an event handler that can only be fired a single time.

Comment: By selector of my link, do you mean the 'a' tag? How would I do that outside of the AJAX function? since I'm gonna hace multiple tags on my datatable (I assign the ID of the item to each one) but I don't know which one is the client going to click beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative without using jQuery for those who are not using that library, is to create a function that can only be fired once. You can use a variable to track this, but my favorite way is to define a property on the function itself:

```
var addRow = function () {
    if (!addRow.hasRun) {
        // Do whatever addRow() usually does

        addRow.hasRun = true;
    }
};
```